# Propagate the changes made in Analysis Service's Cube in Performance Point Dashboards

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, cube, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I have several performance point dashboards in SharePoint 2010 made from several cubes containing several measures and dimensions. Earlier, the measures and dimensions had too long name. Now their names has been shortened. After the changes has been made in the cubes, rather than seeing the new changes, I am seeing errors ever where. I tested the connections for every cube in Dashboard Designers and they looks fine. I closed and re-opened the Dashboard Designer but it did not help. Redoing everything again will be long and hectic job. Please let me know of any workarounds you have.

Thank you

Merin

Comment: I do not know Performance Point, hence I do not know how the queries are saved there. But if you have access to them somehow, you can do an automated search and replace of old  names with new ones, as this mapping should be available if you did the renaming. At least that is what we do in our own client tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your worksapce your dev machine as a workspace file (.ddwx). You can do that by selecting File --> Save As in the Dashboard Designer. The .ddwx file is an XML file that you can open in Notepad. Search and replace old dimension names with new ones. Open up the file in Dashboard Designer and re-publish.